# command line argument interferes with output redirection

Tags: python, macos, shell, zsh

I found `|& tee` [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) to send the `StdErr` and `StdOut` to a file. Right now am using a Mac, and that works fine for a basic example:

**hello.py**

```
print("hello world")

print(1/0)
```

in the Mac terminal :

```
python hello.py |& tee hello.txt
```

The following goes both onto the console and is written to a file:

```
hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

My actual program has a command line argument, so when I enter:

```
python run_process.py DEBUG |& tee process_log_27Mar18.txt
```

..it just does not seem to produce any output. Not sure if it runs at all. It creates a file, but it is empty. Without the second half of that line past 'DEBUG' it instantly starts printing stuff to the console.

Is something else meant to go in there when it has a command line argument like that or is this a Mac peculiarity?

Comment: Please post your actual program, or modify your sample to take an argument, ensure that the error still persists, and post that. Also, you have tags for both bash and zsh. Which are you using?

Comment: It's zsh on MacOS. I did not write the program an it does not seem to take in its argument with argparse. I think it's more a terminal thing, does it look like it should work with that argument there?

Comment: I would agree that it's almost certainly a terminal thing -- but it's also possible that program just does something weird when DEBUG is passed. Without seeing the internals, it's tough to know. I don't have zsh or a mac, but try another program (a built in mac one) using an arg and tee, see if it works. If so, then it's the program, assuming nothing else changed.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that the program checks whether a variable equal to `sys.argv[1]` is either 'DEBUG' or 'LIVE'. Will see if I can get a Mac terminal to switch to something other than zsh, (am normally a linux user..)

Comment: This almost certainly has nothing to do with either `zsh` or the terminal. Instead, the output is buffered when writing to a pipe, and your program isn't producing enough output to fill the buffer immediately. Wait long enough, and either the buffer will fill, forcing some output to the screen, or the process will end, flushing the buffer to the file/terminal.

Comment: Ok @chepner well thanks for confirming that this is a legitimate  `zsh` command. I contented myself for now with a command that just wrote to file not to console but will test this command next time I need to do this and be more patient with it.

Comment: @chepner you are right I used the command again, gave it time and it flushed both to the terminal and into the file.